# How can I add records to my SQLite database, using PySide2, that have NULL values?

Tags: python, pyside2, qwidget, qtableview, qstyleditemdelegate

I have a PySide2 GUI that can add, update and delete records in my SQLite3 database. I use QTableView to view the data and QDataWidgetMapper to edit data.

My problem is that when I add a record to the database that has a blank value in any field it does not register as a NULL value in the database, only a blank string (""). I don't think I am implementing the delegate in the correct way. Should I be setting the delegate on the column or on the QDataWidgetMapper?

```
import sys
import os
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
import PySide2.QtUiTools as QtUiTools
import sqlite3


class NullDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NullDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if index.siblingAtColumn(1).data() == "":  # This is for testing purposes
            print(index.siblingAtColumn(2).data())
        if index.data():
            editor.setText(str(index.data()))
        editor.selectAll()  # This is for testing purposes

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = editor.text()
        if value == "":
            print("null value")
            model.setData(index, None, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        else:
            model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        # load ui file
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        # The UI file must be a widget, NOT MainWindow, to load into a QMainWindow object
        # otherwise you will have to use .show() to open in separate window
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.ui")
        self.main = loader.load(path, self)

        # create SQLite Database and Table
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName("customers_demo.db")
        if db.open():
            print('connection open')
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(db=db)
        query.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customers_demo (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, FEIN varchar(255), CustomerName varchar(255), Address varchar(255), City varchar(255), State varchar(255), Zip INT) ")
        query.exec_()

        # Set up QSqlTableModel
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("customers_demo")
        self.model.select()

        # Set up QDataWidgetMapper
        self.mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)

        # Set up the delegate for null values
        null_delegate = NullDelegate(self.main.tableView)
        self.mapper.setItemDelegate(null_delegate)

        # Configure QDataWidgetMapper
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.main.id_lineEdit, 0)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.main.fein_lineEdit, 1)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.main.customer_lineEdit, 2)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.main.address_lineEdit, 3)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.main.city_lineEdit, 4)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.main.state_lineEdit, 5)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.main.zip_lineEdit, 6)
        self.mapper.setSubmitPolicy(self.mapper.ManualSubmit)

        # Set up QTableView
        self.main.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        # Set up the delegate for null values
        # null_delegate = NullDelegate(self.main.tableView)
        # self.main.tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, null_delegate)
        self.main.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()

        # QTableView properties
        self.main.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)  # sort by clicking title
        self.main.tableView.resizeColumnToContents(2)  # "Customer Name" column
        self.main.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        # add background color to every other row
        self.main.tableView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        # make table uneditable
        self.main.tableView.setEditTriggers(
            QtWidgets.QTableView.NoEditTriggers)

        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(0)
        print(self.mapper.currentIndex())

        self.RECORD_NUMBER()
        self.handle_buttons()

    def handle_buttons(self):
        self.main.update_btn.clicked.connect(self.UPDATE)
        self.main.delete_btn.clicked.connect(self.DELETE)
        self.main.new_btn.clicked.connect(self.NEW)
        self.main.first_btn.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toFirst)
        self.main.first_btn.clicked.connect(self.RECORD_NUMBER)
        self.main.previous_btn.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toPrevious)
        self.main.previous_btn.clicked.connect(self.RECORD_NUMBER)
        self.main.next_btn.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toNext)
        self.main.next_btn.clicked.connect(self.RECORD_NUMBER)
        self.main.last_btn.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toLast)
        self.main.last_btn.clicked.connect(self.RECORD_NUMBER)
        self.main.tableView.clicked.connect(self.SELECT_ROW)

    def SELECT_ROW(self, item):

        # Set text to the selected customer info
        self.main.id_lineEdit.setText(
            str(item.siblingAtColumn(0).data()))  # convert int to str
        self.main.customer_lineEdit.setText(item.siblingAtColumn(2).data())
        self.main.fein_lineEdit.setText(item.siblingAtColumn(1).data())
        self.main.address_lineEdit.setText(item.siblingAtColumn(3).data())
        self.main.city_lineEdit.setText(item.siblingAtColumn(4).data())
        self.main.state_lineEdit.setText(item.siblingAtColumn(5).data())
        self.main.zip_lineEdit.setText(
            str(item.siblingAtColumn(6).data()))  # convert int to str
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(item.row())
        self.RECORD_NUMBER()

    def UPDATE(self):
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dialog.ui")
        dialog = loader.load(path)

        currentIndex = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        print("Mapper", currentIndex)
        self.main.tableView.selectRow(currentIndex)

        customer = self.main.tableView.currentIndex().siblingAtColumn(2).data()
        print(customer)

        text = f"Are you sure you want to UPDATE {customer} info?"
        dialog.label.setText(text)

        dialog.buttonBox.accepted.connect(dialog.accept)
        dialog.buttonBox.rejected.connect(dialog.reject)

        dialog.show()

        if dialog.exec_():
            print("update")
            te = self.mapper.submit()
            print(te)
            print(self.mapper.model())

            self.model.select()
        else:
            pass

    def DELETE(self):
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dialog.ui")
        dialog = loader.load(path)

        currentIndex = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        print("Mapper", currentIndex)
        self.main.tableView.selectRow(currentIndex)
        customer = self.main.tableView.currentIndex().siblingAtColumn(2).data()
        print(customer)

        text = f"Are you sure you want to DELETE {customer} info?"
        dialog.label.setText(text)

        dialog.buttonBox.accepted.connect(dialog.accept)
        dialog.buttonBox.rejected.connect(dialog.reject)

        dialog.show()

        if dialog.exec_():
            print("yes")

            self.model.removeRow(currentIndex)

            self.model.select()
        else:
            pass
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(0)
        print(self.mapper.currentIndex())
        self.RECORD_NUMBER()

    def NEW(self):
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dialog.ui")
        dialog = loader.load(path)

        customer = self.main.customer_lineEdit.text()
        text = f"Are you sure you want to ADD {customer} info?"
        dialog.label.setText(text)

        dialog.buttonBox.accepted.connect(dialog.accept)
        dialog.buttonBox.rejected.connect(dialog.reject)

        dialog.show()

        if dialog.exec_():
            row = self.model.rowCount()
            record = self.model.record()
            # record.setGenerated('id', False)
            record.setValue('ID', self.main.id_lineEdit.text())
            record.setValue('FEIN', str(self.main.fein_lineEdit.text()))
            record.setValue("CustomerName",
                            self.main.customer_lineEdit.text())
            record.setValue('Address', self.main.address_lineEdit.text())
            record.setValue('City', self.main.city_lineEdit.text())
            record.setValue('State', self.main.state_lineEdit.text())
            record.setValue('Zip', self.main.zip_lineEdit.text())
            self.model.insertRecord(row, record)

            self.model.select()
        else:
            pass
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(0)
        print(self.mapper.currentIndex())
        self.RECORD_NUMBER()

    def RECORD_NUMBER(self):
        currentIndex = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        print(currentIndex)
        rows = self.model.rowCount()
        self.main.record_label.setText(
            f"Customer {currentIndex+1} of {rows} customers")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Main()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

You can download the ui files and a sample database [here.](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/rl45dx06j93ji/qtsql_null)

Also I'm using Python 3.7.4

Comment: Does the library not convert from [Python's] `None` to `null` on the SQL-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the delegate but in the code that adds the row since you are passing the text of the QLineEdits directly without implementing the logic of the nulls.

```py
def NEW(self):
    loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dialog.ui")
    dialog = loader.load(path)

    customer = self.main.customer_lineEdit.text()
    text = f"Are you sure you want to ADD {customer} info?"
    dialog.label.setText(text)

    dialog.buttonBox.accepted.connect(dialog.accept)
    dialog.buttonBox.rejected.connect(dialog.reject)

    if dialog.exec_():
        mapping = {
            "ID": self.main.id_lineEdit,
            "FEIN": self.main.fein_lineEdit,
            "CustomerName": self.main.customer_lineEdit,
            "Address": self.main.address_lineEdit,
            "City": self.main.city_lineEdit,
            "State": self.main.state_lineEdit,
            "Zip": self.main.zip_lineEdit,
        }
        record = self.model.record()
        for fieldname, lineedit in mapping.items():
            text = lineedit.text()
            record.setValue(fieldname, text if text else None)
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRecord(row, record)
        self.model.select()
    self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(0)
    print(self.mapper.currentIndex())
    self.RECORD_NUMBER()
```